# Batch file contents while echoing showing extra characters?

Tags: batch-file

I have written the following code in my batch file.

```
find /I "login" vtst_rws3220579.xml > Login.txt
```

when the batch file is run, it is echoing like this.

```
find /I "login" vtst_rws3220579.xml 1> Login.txt
```

Here if we observe the echoed statment, before redirection operator character '1' is added.
Due to which my statement is not executing.

Can any one help me to find out how to solve this issue?

Comment: The `1>` is normal in NT and it shows that STDOUT is being redirected.  There is some other issue and you'll have to describe what is meant to happen, and what is actually happening at the moment.

Comment: Both `>` and `1>` mean redirection of standard output to a file (`2>` is a redirection of standard error output). The added '1' should not affect `cmd.exe` in any way. Is there any error message `cmd.exe` gives you?

Comment: Can you post part of source file and output for that bit of the file?

Comment: Edit your question, don't put more information in an answer.  The syntax you show will not generate an error and will work fine, if the file exists, the text is within the file, and you have write permissions where you are running the command

Answer (score 0):

put this line in batch file and run bit then you came to know the problem exactly what i am facing.

```
find /I "login" vtst_rws3220579.xml > Login.txt
```